# Tableau + NodeJS — Download view as csv

Tags: node.js, request, tableau-api

Using this [Tableau API page](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_auth.htm#Python2) I've been able to build the request that gets the api token for subsequent requests.

However, I'm having difficulty using this token to download the contents of a csv view, like what happens when you visit the url in a browser.

I've built the request below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
{
    'url': 'https://<server>/#/site/Project1/views/View1/sheet1.csv',
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': {
        'X-Tableau-Auth': dataToken.credentials.token,
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
        'Cookie': 'workgroup_session_id=' + dataToken.credentials.token
    }
}
```

All I get back is the dom html, rather than the csv download content. If I remove the '#/site' from the url, it complains the url is malformed.

I've looked online extensively, and have not been able to find anything that covers this. There's some python scripts that people seem to use, but I can't make sense of it and am not sure if it handles what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the useful api docs that cover this:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_View_Data%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____75

You need to know the view's id number which you can get from other api's in the above. Once you have that, the url for getting the data as csv is simple (copied from url above):

```
/api/<api-version>/sites/<site-id>/views/<view-id>/data
```